# Trying to understand mutable closures in Rust

Tags: rust, closures

I am a newby Rustacean (completing the rustling course, and so far enjoying it a lot). I am having trouble with some examples of closures in the Rust book. In particular, this one:

```rust
fn main() {     

    let mut list = vec![1, 2, 3];     

    let mut borrows_mutably = || list.push(7);      

    borrows_mutably();     
}
```

The fact that we need to declare the closure as `mut` is difficult for me to understand. And it's really needed, because if you don't declare it as mut, the compiler complains:

```
calling `borrows_mutably` requires mutable binding due to mutable borrow of `list`
   |         |
   |         help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut borrows_mutably`
   |
   |     borrows_mutably();
   |     ^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

I have read many posts here and there and my understanding was that the closure was required to be defined as `mut` because it's mutating its environment. I don't know if this intuition is correct or not...

Anyway, playing with another closures I found an example that broke my understanding. This one:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut num_ops = 0;
    let func = |r: &i32| {
        num_ops += 1;
        r.abs()
    };
    let mut list = [-3, 1, 5];
    list.sort_by_key(func);
    println!("{:?}, {}", list, num_ops);
}
```

I have a closure that is used for sorting a list of integers by their absolute value and by counting how many operations took place. Clearly, this closure is mutating its environment as well. But I don't need to declare it as `mut` in this case because, it seems, instead of calling the closure in my code, I am passing it to another function (`sort_by_key`) which, in turn, will call it. Why this behaviour?

I find it super confusing. In fact, if instead of passing the function to `sort_by_key` I call it directly, I get the same error (`cannot borrow func as mutable...`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have read many posts here and there and my understanding was that the closure was requiered to be defined as `mut` because it's mutating its environment. I don't know if this intuition is correct or not...

Yes, this is correct.  Under the hood, the closure value captures a mutable reference to `list`.  In other words, the `borrows_mutably` value contains a `&mut Vec<_>` and it is with this reference that `Vec::push` is invoked.

So why does `borrows_mutably` need to be declared `mut`?  First, note that accessing a mutable reference *through a shared reference* does not allow mutable access.  This is why the invocation signature for `FnMut` closures takes `&mut self` -- if it took `&self` then the `&mut` would be behind a `&`, and `& &mut` behaves the same as `& &`.  Because the `FnMut` invocation must take `&mut self`, `borrows_mutably` needs to be declared `mut`.

> But I don't need to declare it as `mut` in this case because, it seems, instead of calling the closure in my code, I am passing it to another function (`sort_by_key`) which, in turn, will call it.

Mutability is a property of the binding, not of the value.  If you take an immutable binding and assign it to a mutable binding, you can mutate it.

For example, this fails to compile:

```
let foo = vec![1];
foo.push(2);
```

But this does compile!

```
let foo = vec![1];
let mut foo2 = foo;
foo2.push(2);
```

We simply moved the value in `foo` into a different, mutable binding.  Now we can mutate it.

The same thing is happening with `sort_by_key`, except it's obfuscated by the function call.  When you pass the closure to this function, you are *giving it away.*  The `sort_by_key` function receives this argument [in a mutable binding](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#300), where it can now be invoked:

```
pub fn sort_by_key<K, F>(&mut self, mut f: F)
//                                  ^^^
```

Note that the mutability of `f` is *not* part of the function signature, which is why it doesn't appear in the documentation.  Mutability of arguments is a detail private to the function -- it's not the caller's business whether the function plans to mutate any of the values it was given.

To clarify, an `FnMut` closure value can be stored in an immutable binding, but cannot be invoked from there.  It needs to be moved into a mutable binding to be invoked.  The line `list.sort_by_key(func);` is what does this in your code, it's just not immediately apparent.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this wonderful explanation. I had a misconception about mutability (it's a property of the binding, not the value!), and now everything makes sense. 

Only thing that I don't understand from your answer (sorry, it's my fault, but I would like to understand it all) is the second paragraph, that starts with "So why does borrows_mutably need to be declared mut?"

Comment: @JaimeArboledaCastilla a mutable binding "allows" the compiler to create a mutable borrow, and a mutable borrow is required to mutate even through a mutable reference (aka `let mut a = &mut b`), otherwise it would be possible to take multiple shared references to a mutable reference and mutate through them, essentially laundering aliased mutable references. It's a bit strange with ownership because you'd assume it doesn't matter, but it's a consequence of Rust's decision to interpret "const" bindings strictly.